# How to connect solana wallet in android?

Tags: solana, wallet, nft, decentralized-applications

I want to make nft marketplace with solana in android.
There are many examples connecting solana wallet(ex. solflare, phantom ...) in web client.
But i don't know how to connect wallet in android dapp.

Comment: The phone experience is still not great for a lot of these web3 apps.  Typically, they all run through a browser in the end.  For example, the Phantom app is actually a browser with their extension built around it. So in the end, it all works as a web app.  With that said, there's lots of room for development in native apps!

Comment: Have you figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can currently, it is something the mobile wallets need to implement an integration for first, it seems.

I/we had the same question, see these:

- https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/309
- https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/311
- https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/312
- https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/319

**Suggestion:** If you had a particular mobile wallet you wanted to use, like [Phantom](https://phantom.app/) which provides a Web Browser feature, you could use that to load marketplaces that have wallet adapter functionality, which can potentially hook into the native app Wallet flows e.g. [Metaplex](https://www.metaplex.com/) + Phantom, which I've been able to connect dev wallets to.